# 70's - 80's Sci-fi TV episode where an alien suit is grafting onto its host

Tags: story-identification, buck-rogers

I just had a vague flash of memory of an old TV show with lots of people wearing a new, "trendy" *spacesuit* (One of those shiny foil jumpsuits meant to be "normal" clothing in the future).  It's later revealed that the suit is actually an alien lifeform that is grafting itself onto the host's body and controlling their minds.

It feels like this might've been a Buck Rogers episode.

Anyone remember where this is from?

Comment: see also this previous post about a 1990s remake of the series: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202561/youths-can-teleport-they-are-chased-by-the-government

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an episode of the 1970's show The Tomorrow People with something similar, called [The Living Skins: A Harmless Fashion](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0726273/)

You can see the first episode here; the suits show up towards the end - you can see a couple of the cast in them at around 11 minutes in.

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xa0xzr_the-tomorrow-people-the-living-skin_shortfilms

This is what the jumpsuits look like. Remember, this was the 1970s, so this was the height of fashion:

[image]

Comment: Bubbleskin jumpsuits! The fashionable teens all wanted one