# 1990's series - British children develop ESP, discover alien spaceship, refuse to use weapons, strong anti-violence message

Tags: story-identification, tv, ancient-races, extrasensory-perception

I saw this TV series in English in the USA in the early 1990's, but many of the characters had British accents and I suspect the series was likely British in origin. I remember racing home as a child so I could see the next episode.

The story starts with some tweens in the UK testing each other for ESP using a deck of playing cards. The boys would look at a card and dare another to guess which one it was. One of the boys, when giving the test to another, glances down at an auto racing magazine instead of concentrating on the card, and the other boy announces "Three...of car?...You're confusing me!" The first boy takes this as strong evidence that they have actually discovered ESP.

The boys figure out (possibly through tabloid media, there was no Internet) that there are other children who may have the same powers living in the USA, so they make plans to travel there. It turns out that the boy with ESP doesn't have a passport, so he has to borrow the passport of the other boy's sister. There is a comedy scene in which the girl-passport carrying boy successfully makes it through US immigration in a dress and a Little House on the Prairie-style bonnet (to conceal his short hair). There is then an argument over which restroom the boy should use to switch back to his regular clothes.

The two boys successfully meet up with at least one American tween with psychic powers, but the meeting is short-lived as it turns out that both US and British authorities have discovered their powers and want to take them back to a lab for experimentation. One of the children manages to disarm one of the agents but appears to go catatonic when he tries to point the gun at someone - apparently having psychic powers makes it difficult for you to harm another.

The children escape from the government agents, growing in power, eventually discovering an ancient, crashed alien spaceship that seems to be calling out to them. They then form a pact to become a nonviolent team of enhanced humans for general peacekeeping and humanitarian purposes, using the crashed spaceship as their home base.

In retrospect, the series had a lot of Stargate-esque tropes - ancient aliens, government conspiracies, etc., but this definitely was *not* Stargate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the 1990s version of *[The Tomorrow People](https://thetomorrowpeople.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tomorrow_People_(1990s_Series_serial))*.

> Megabyte is giving Kevin an ESP test where he has to predict cards. Kevin gets all of them right, even sensing the number on the magazine Megabyte looks at. Megabyte thinks this is evidence Kevin is telepathic. Kevin accuses Megabyte of transmitting thoughts to him. Megabyte dismisses the idea but Kevin is upset that he isn't "normal". Lisa and her mother arrive at the hall where the talent contest is. Lisa has an uncomfortable encounter with one of her peers, Sammi, who is amused at the idea of her competing.

....

> .... Megabyte retrieves his passport and Kevin learns his real name is Marmaduke. He then realises Kevin doesn't have a passport so decides he can use his sister Millicent's.
>
> Lisa is expelled by the ship, getting a soft landing on the tent. Meanwhile, Kevin and Megabyte arrive at the airport, with Kevin dressed as a girl. Kevin goes to the bathroom to get changed...but, encountering a pair of scary bikers, wonders which one he should use.....

Yes, the government is pursuing them. One consequence of their evolved nature is their inability to kill other sapiens. And yes, aliens and advanced technology after key to the series.

Found with a search for `tv series british children psychic powers pacifist`

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202561/youths-can-teleport-they-are-chased-by-the-government/202563?r=SearchResults#202563

Comment: At least one of the actors in this was Australian rather than British (Kristian Schmid).

Comment: Yes, I was about to add that one of the most significant aspects of the show was that it starred Kristian Schmid at his most gorgeous  ;)

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez Kristian Schmid is as gorgeous today as he’s ever been, [just look at that](https://static0.colliderimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/saturday-night-live-bill-hader.png)

Comment: Thanks so much! This is it!

Comment: ^_^ I remember when this one aired on Nickelodeon when I was a kid. I was surprised to learn it was a remake.